# Problems Pasting one DF into Another using R tool (ALTERYX v11)

Tags: r, rstudio, alteryx

This code works just fine in RSTUDIO:

```
pos1<- min(which(is.na(extract[1,])==FALSE))
pos2<-(min(which(is.na(extract[1,])==FALSE & extract[1,]%in%hh[,1]==FALSE))-1)

set1<-extract[1, pos1:pos2]

repsc<-length(which(is.na(set1[1,])==TRUE))/length(which(is.na(set1[1,])==FALSE)) 

  set2<-set1[is.na(set1[1,])==FALSE,]
    set2[,is.na(set2[1,])==TRUE]<-NULL
      set2<-set2[-c(2,3),]

set1[1,]<-rep(set2,1,each=(repsc+1))  
    extract[1,pos1:pos2]<-set1
```

Which turns this:

```
           X8   X9  X10      X11  X12   X13    X14  X15  X16
5 HH Live <NA> <NA> HH Live+ <NA>  <NA> HH Com <NA> <NA>
6         <NA> <NA>    1 Day <NA> 2 Day     C3 <NA>   C7
7     Rtg   Sh   AA      Rtg   AA   Rtg    Rtg   AA  Rtg
```

To this:

```
       X8      X9     X10      X11      X12      X13    X14    X15    X16
5 HH Live HH Live HH Live HH Live+ HH Live+ HH Live+ HH Com HH Com HH Com
6            <NA>    <NA>    1 Day     <NA>    2 Day     C3   <NA>     C7
7     Rtg      Sh      AA      Rtg       AA      Rtg    Rtg     AA    Rtg
```

However, in the Alteryx R tool two things happen:

1) set1 doesn't copy over into extract, which means it doesn't replicate HH LIVE, HH LIVE+, and HH COM into row 1.  One line of code seems to be screwing it all up (works in RSTUDIO, not R TOOL in Alteryx:

```
extract[1,pos1:pos2]<-set1
```

2) I get this warning message in Alteryx:

```
R (2)   1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 89L) :
R (2)   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I've checked my data types - they are all factors and both objects are class "data.frame."

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

That error message comes from trying to put a new value into a factor that doesn't exist in the levels already. For example:

```
> x=factor(c("eggs","bacon","eggs","eggs"))
> x
[1] eggs  bacon eggs  eggs 
Levels: bacon eggs
```

Now I try and make the first item something that isn't in the `levels()`:

```
> x[1]="cheese"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = "cheese") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
>
```

And that's the error you get. So now you need to debug this by, perhaps printing out what it is trying to do at that point, or using the debugger or the `browser()` function to stop the code and inspect what it is doing at that point.

Without all your data we've not much hope of helping you more.